# Why do we use $q_{\phi}(z \mid x^{(i)})$ in the objective function of amortized variational inference, while sometimes we use $q(z)$?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, notation, variational-inference

In page 21 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JV-Rsz1MECZWWtvdXjxnt03HOxiGWPYy/view), it states:

> **General Idea of Amortization**: if same inference problem needs to be solved many times, can we parameterize a neural network to solve it?
>
> **Our case**: for all $x^{(i)}$ we want to solve:
> $$
> \min _{q(z)} \mathrm{KL}\left(q(z) \| p_{\theta}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right)\right.
> $$
> **Amortized formulation**:
> $$
> \min _{\phi} \sum \operatorname{KL}\left(q_{\phi}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right) \| p_{\theta}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right)\right)
> $$

One thing I am trying to wrap my mind around is $q(z)$ in the 1st formulation vs $q_{\phi}(z \mid x^{(i)})$ in the second.

Why is one a conditioned on $x^{(i)}$ and the other is not? I know in the 1st formulation, we are trying to find a different $q(z)$ for each datapoint.

I also recall that in VAEs,which uses amortized inference we consider $q(z)$ to be aggregated posterior, like

$$q_{\phi}(z)=\int q_{\phi}(x, z) d x \quad \text { Marginal of } q_{\phi}(x, z) \text { on } z$$

$$q_{\phi}(x, z) \equiv p_{\mathcal{D}}(x) q_{\phi}(z \mid x)$$

(formulas taken from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02262.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

The reason is indeed the difference between **traditional** variational inference and the **amortized** variational inference.

In traditional VI, the objective is to solving the following problem for every datapoint $x^{(i)}$
$$\min _{q(z)} \mathrm{KL}\left(q(z) \| p_{\theta}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right)\right)$$
Pay attention that if we write out explicitly the variational parameter  $\phi$, it should depend on i-th datapoint (hence we call them *local parameters*), i.e. we are in fact solving N problems provided N is the number of datapoints.
$$\min _{\phi_i} \mathrm{KL}\left(q_{\phi_i}(z) \| p_{\theta}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right)\right)$$

while for amortized VI, we try to find a *global variational parameter* that serves for the inference of all the datapoints, i.e.
$$\min _{\phi} \sum_{i=1}^N \operatorname{KL}\left(q_{\phi}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right) \| p_{\theta}\left(z \mid x^{(i)}\right)\right)$$

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10888) explains the difference with better notations.